# SQL Server 2012, triggers missing after restore database

Tags: sql-server, trigger, restore

I am using MS SQL Management Studio 2012 to restore the database from a `.bak` file.  (That file is from the backup of the database on server)

In my new database, the triggers are missing. Why did I lose the triggers?

Comment: A .bak file is a complete database backup (if it's a full backup and not a differential or log, which are different types). But if your restore works and finishes successfully, everything that was in the original DB will also be in the copy. So the triggers should be in the restored database. Don't have an SQL 2012 to play with now, but they should be under Tables -> Your Table Name -> Triggers.

Comment: Restore was successfully. On server there are triggers on that location (Tables -> Your Table Name -> Triggers), but when i open the database on my local machine that triggers doesn't extst.

Comment: What's the version of SQL Server Management Studio on your local machine?

Comment: How have you validated the triggers?  Have you checked `SELECT * FROM [foo].[sys].[triggers]` where foo is the name of your database?  All objects should have been restored with the database backup, as @Marian stated.

Comment: It's SQL Server 2012. Whit that query am not getting anything. There isn't any trigger.

Comment: Are you restoring the backup to a different server than where the backup was taken?

Answer (score 2):

A wild guess - are the triggers based on CLR code? If CLR Integration has not been enabled on the machine you are restoring to then the triggers won't work.

CLR Integration can be enabled with the following code.

```
exec sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
exec sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Comment: I executed that query, nothing changed. 
Is it possible that the problem is with users on database or with privillages?

Comment: will i need to restore again after doing above?  how to check current settings?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the backup was created before the triggers were put into the database.  Make sure that the backup is current.  SQL Server won't just drop the triggers when it restores the database backup.

Comment: No, it's not that. Backup is from last night, that database is in use for 2 years, so something else is the problem.

Comment: Then something is removing the triggers after the database has been restored.